# Preciso criar uma extensão para Google Chrome que execute um .exe ou Algo similar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Preciso fazer com que meu Website execute um sistema local (seu .exe), passando alguns atributos pelo executavel, quero fazer uma extensão para Google Chrome que eu possa passar os parâmetros pra ela executar o programa. Como faço isso? Caso não seja possível, tem como fazer algo similar?

Comment: Isso esta me cheirando vírus no micro dos usuários hein, extensão do Chrome que execute um .exe rs

Comment: Preciso passar as informações da venda para realizar a emissão do SAT CF-e pelo sistema desktop.

Comment: Você ja começou a desenvolver alguma coisa? Já tem algum código pronto? a dúvida em si é de programação ou uma estratégia de como fazê-lo?

Comment: Tenho um emissor desktop, ele recebe parâmetros pelo seu arquivo exe no momento da execução para abrir e realizar a emissão, mas como estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, preciso de passar essas informações do navegador para o emissor e executa-lo para ele realizar a emissão

Comment: Isso tipicamente é feito server-side: a sua extensão faria uma requisição para um servidor, instruindo ele a fazer a emissão

Answer (score 3):

Isto não é possivel, não existe maneira de contornar pois é intencional que não seja possivel (por razões de segurança) que seja possivel disparar um executável

O que você pode fazer é tentar recriar o seu .exe como uma WebExtension ou como um ChromeApp, no caso do ChromeApp você pode chama-lo pela primeira extensão usando https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connectNative

Era possivel anteriormente usar *NPAPI* para carregar dlls, mas o NPAPI foi removido.

<s>Todavia note que é possível usar [NPAPI](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi) para carregar DLLs por exemplo:</s>

O manifest.json deve estar assim:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "plugins": [
    { "path": "extension_plugin.dll" }
  ],
  ...
}
```

O uso deve ser algo como:

```
<embed type="application/x-my-extension" id="pluginId">
<script>
  var plugin = document.getElementById("pluginId");
  var result = plugin.myPluginMethod();  // call a method in your plugin
  console.log("my plugin returned: " + result);
</script>
```

Comment: NPAPI foi removido de forma permanente do Chrome em setembro de 2015 https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=pt-BR

Comment: @rodorgas bem lembrado, editado

Answer (score -2):

Uma ideia é disponibilizar um instalador adicional (um serviço do windows por exemplo) que abra uma porta de comunicação http, e você se comunicar diretamente com ele via localhost.